# Git on Windows: fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: node.js, git, bower, bower-install

I'm trying to use Git on Windows by using this command on prompt

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
```

And I'm receiving this error:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I was following [this tutorial](http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/a-simple-tutorial-of-setting-up-and-using-bower-on-windows/) on Web and I'm wondering what is happening (firewall or anything else).

I'm noob with git so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of network are you on? I know our corporate net blocks the `git` protocol.

Comment: corporate! And we are trying to unblock it without success

Comment: Did you try https instead of the git protocol?

Comment: No, because I'm using bower and I have no idea how to change from git protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my corporate firewall has blocked the git protocol.
I change git to use https protocol, so it works.

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```